# Application client module within WAR packaging possible?

Tags: java-ee-6, war

Since Java EE 6 I can package my Java EE application including EJBs into a WAR instead of an EAR.

Can I also include an application client module in such a WAR package and if so how would I do it with maven?

Comment: This is interesting. As you had asked the question, you might have such a requirement. Please help me understand, 1. under what circumstances would an application client module would fit to be part of a WAR file? 2. How would the client access it? Thanks.

Comment: @user1418717 whoo, this question is 7 years old now - as the client counterpart of an EJB for demonstration purposes I bundled an application client module in an ear, where I could start a main class which was able to access the EJB - I asked myself at that time, if I could do the same in an war - but this is not possible, since the war is only the server part and does not contain client code.